# Sibling span(s) positioning relative to each other

Tags: css

I have two `span`(s) positioned adjacent to one another within a parent `div`.

```
<div>
    <span id="x1"> </span>
    <span id="x2"> </span>
</div>
```

I want the 2nd `span` to be shown leftmost & then 1st span. (Note: for some reasons I cannot  simply move the 2nd span in place of 1st span in html code). How can I display 2nd span on leftmost ?

## Edit:

`float:left;` on 2nd span seems to do the trick but not sure if this would be cross browser consistent in terms of this behavior!?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `float: left` css.

It is supported in all browsers.

**HTML**

```
<div><span>Will be leftmost</span><span>Will be right most</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div span {float: left;}
```

Note that adding `float` on spans will cause them to not be inline elements, if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

That is doing the trick :

```
span#x2 {
    float:left;
}
```

See on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXNrG/).

It is cross-browser.